# How to disable a link to call a phone number when not on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, media-queries, href

What I would like to build is a button that will allow the user to call in. On desktop this element will look like a big call-to-action, 
[image: On desktop]

then on mobile this will be both a call-to-action and an actual method to call. 
[image: On mobile]

The challenge that I need to address now is that the ability to call should be only present when on mobile. This is my current code:

```
<div id="headerCTA">
  <div>
    <a href="tel:888-336-1301">
      <div>
        Schedule a pickup<br>
        888-336-1301
      </div>  
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[[Code gist on GitHub - for additional commenting]](https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/6136023)

But when on desktop (dictated by screen width?) this link should be deactivated. At the moment if someone happens to click on this from desktop, it attempts to open a page as "tel:888-336-1301"

Which produces the following error:

The address wasn't understood
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (tel) isn't associated with any program.

Comment: I don't see a need to "fix" this as it is expetected behaviour. Its possible to bind the tel-protocol to certain programs, that lets you make calls from you desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mobile detection script, like the one in the accepted answer here: [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser)

Then

```
var mobile = mobilecheck();
if (!mobile) {
  document.getElementById('telephone-link').href = '#';
}
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I am looking for. So from how I read this, first you are defining the variable of mobile, then your function if not mobile, will select the href, but then what is it doing?

Comment: It's setting the href to a "dummy" hash value. A hash takes you no-where, so essentially the link becomes disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Another idea, that doesn't involve JavaScript, is to use CSS `pointer-events` property. Use media query to target devices that may not have the ability to make calls and for them, set `pointer-events` property to `none`. This way, clicking on the link won't have any effect.

Your code could look like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px){
  #headerCTA a{
   pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

See [`pointer-events` property documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for details.